# Using Authy with PyPI 2FA

Tags: pypi, authy

PyPI recently required 2FA be enabled for all accounts.

I've used the Authy app for 2FA on other sites, so I chose it for PyPI too.

Authy accepted PyPI's QR code and generates the standard 6 digit code, but when I enter it into PyPI's "Verify application" field and click "Set up application", it gives me the error "Invalid TOTP code. Try again?" even though the timer hasn't expired.

I tried a few more times with different codes, but it refuses to accept any Authy codes.

Is there something I'm missing? Does PyPI use some different 2FA/TOTP standard not supported by the Authy app?